# Cannot run python on windows. What am I missing?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, glade, pygobject

I am pretty new to python. Please correct me if I show stupidity.

So I am trying to run the following code:

```
    from gi.repository import Gtk
class LisaMainWindow:

  def on_LisaMainWindow_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print ("quit with cancel")
    Gtk.main_quit()

  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "lisaMainWindow.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    print ("gtk builder done")
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    print ("glade loaded")
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("lisaMainWindow")
    self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = Buglump()
  Gtk.main()
```

And I get the following error

```
** (python.exe:6388): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libgtk-3-0.dll'
 referenced by the typelib: 'libgtk-3-0.dll': The specified module could not be
found.

** (python.exe:6388): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libgdk-3-0.dll'
 referenced by the typelib: 'libgdk-3-0.dll': The specified module could not be
found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lisaMainWindow.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\importer.py", line 67, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\module.py", line 296, in _load
    self._overrides_module = importlib.import_module('gi.overrides.' + self._nam
espace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\overrides\Gtk.py", line 118, in <module
>
    class Widget(Gtk.Widget):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\module.py", line 183, in __getattr__
    interfaces = tuple(interface for interface in get_interfaces_for_object(info
)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\module.py", line 109, in get_interfaces
_for_object
    interfaces.append(getattr(module, name))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\module.py", line 320, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\module.py", line 222, in __getattr__
    wrapper = metaclass(name, bases, dict_)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\types.py", line 234, in __init__
    register_interface_info(cls.__info__.get_g_type())
TypeError: must be an interface
```

I am running `Windows 8 on 64 bit`.
Below are my installations to develop a Gtk based GUI.

1. `python-3.4.3.amd64.msi` from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
2. `pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev10-setup.exe` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/

What am I missing or doing wrong ? 
Please help. (thanks in advance)

Comment: Did you install GTK for Windows? The first two warnings say GTK and GDK (the support library for GTK) are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same kind of problem.

To solve it, I have installed GTK3+ from
http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php
the all-in-one bundle of the GTK+ stack including 3rd-party dependencies
at http://win32builder.gnome.org/gtk+-bundle_3.6.4-20130921_win32.zip
after unzip the file in somedir.

You can test it by running `somedir\bin\gtk3-demo.exe`
you have to add the bin dir which contains dll files in the windows PATH
run in console > where libgdk-3-0.dll to check dll are found then run your python file.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue (Although with a different version), Previous release doesn't have this problem.

Works:
pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev15-setup.exe

Doesn't Work:
pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev16-setup.exe

http://softlayer-dal.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pygobjectwin32/pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev15-setup.exe